# In Amazon AppFlow, Salesforce Platform Events are not accessible

Tags: salesforcedx, administration, amazon-s3, amazon-aws

What would prevent our Salesforce (SF) integrations with Amazon EventBridge and Amazon AppFlow, from accessing Platform Events in Salesforce?

From a SF Admin perspective, the integration user has read/create access to the object. I would expect our AWS team to be able to see the Platform Event in AppFlow. There are a few other Platform Events that are not coming through which leads me to believe AWS doesn't have SF's new schema (not sure if there's an automatic sync or manual intervention is needed).

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. The integration between AWS and SF via AppFlow/EventBridge involves quite a few steps and configuration nuances, even if it's kinda sorta out of the box. Your question does not include any of this information with the exception of minimal statement on access.